# Generating given data using python to feed SVM

Tags: python-3.x, svm

Can you help me to generate this kind of data? I tried the nested one with Gaussian and red one with parabolic but have some difficulties merging them to feed SVM.I think, there should be definitely some easy way to achieve this. Will be grateful for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but for what I think you are asking you can use [sklearn.datasets.make_classification](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html#sklearn.datasets.make_classification). It allows you to generate a random n-class classification problem.

Additionally, here is an example with code that generates 3 different [datasets](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-classifier-comparison-py).

Here is the code that is generating the datasets.

```
datasets = [
make_moons(noise=0.3, random_state=0),
make_circles(noise=0.2, factor=0.5, random_state=1),
linearly_separable]
```

Given your image, I would say that you should be using the `make_circles` function.

Comment: Thanks for response. Question is to generate the data that I posted

Comment: The link I provided generates random datasets like what I think you are trying to make. It won't replicate your image but it will make something similar with the right parameters. Look at the documentation.